# Find the size of the set using additive rule

Tags: discrete-mathematics

how do I go about finding set sizes?

Example

|A| = 129;  |B| = 53; |A ∩ B| = 34;  |A ∪ B| =

Comment: Drawing a Venn diagram is very useful here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amount of elements that are in A is 129 
Amount of elements that are in B is 53 
Amount of elements that are in A and in B at the same time is 34 
So
Amount of elements that are only in A is 129-53=95 
Amount of elements that are only in B is 53-34=19

Amount of elements that are in A or in B is equal to amount of elements that are only in A + amount of elements that are only in B + amount of elements that are in both A and B at the same time = 95 + 19 + 34 = 148

That's why $$|A\cup B|=148$$

### Alternative approach

Size of the set $A\cup B $ is equivalent to sum of sizes of $A$ and $B$ with size of $|A\cap B|$ substracted. 
(if you think about it, it seems obvious)

Answer (score 1):

Well, the additive rule (probably) says

$$|A \cup B| = |A| + |B| - |A \cap B|$$

which should be all the info you need.